# How to automate a function

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have written a function called getftp(). The function reads text files of shipping data that are ftp'd to a folder called inbox and submits then into a database. I now just have it set to run on page load but I would like to automate it so that it runs twice per day. I am not sure how to go about that. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Couldn't you create a job within [Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task) to run this for you?

Comment: The problem is don't know how.

Comment: Why not write a C# app that sleeps for 12 hours, calls the function, then goes back to sleep for 12 hours?

Comment: I like the sound of that.Do you have any more info how I would go about that. I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: Search around for Thread.Sleep examples, take a stab at the code, and come back with a new post if you get stuck.

Comment: @robertwoods - Click on 'Windows' in my comment.  I hyperlinked a 'how to' guide.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Agent - accessible on the database through SSMS - allows you to schedule jobs to run on particular schedules.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Agent, as suggested above, or Windows Task Scheduler are your easiest solutions
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993.aspx